# Unable to catch exception NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My `try` block throws `NoSuchElementException` but my `catch` block is unable to proceed.

In my automation suite I get a page with btnOk element sometimes(first login everyday) so I am trying to handle the scenario where if the page comes then click on it and proceed otherwise continue any ways.

Code snippet below:

```
try {
    WebElement submitbuttonPresence=driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk"));
    submitbuttonPresence.click();
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you catch an incorrect exception. Try code below:

```
try {
    WebElement submitbuttonPresence=driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk"));
    submitbuttonPresence.click();
}
catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Buaban - Below is the exception seen         Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btnOk"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Kishore-PC', ip: '135.250.77.106', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: @Ravi Do you mean my code cannot catch the exception?

Comment: Below helped                                                                           replacing "NoSuchElementException" with "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"                                   Exception mentioned in my comment on top is from my code !

Comment: @Ravi It's the same as my answer. By the way, can you mark my answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

There are two `NoSuchElementException`, one in `java.util` and one in `org.openqa.selenium`. To catch `WebDriver` exceptions you need the second one

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```